# What does '$d|z|$' mean?

Tags: complex-analysis, notation, contour-integration

For example, the inequality

$$\left|\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz\right|\leq \int_\gamma |f(z)|\,d|z|. $$

What does '$d|z|$' mean in this context?

Edit: I suppose it's better to mention the whole problem itself. My notes say that

$$\int_{c+iT}^{\infty+iT} y^{\Re(s)}d|s| = \int_{c}^{\infty} y^{\sigma}d\sigma $$

and I don't understand why this is true.

Comment: It would mean arc length along $\gamma.$

Comment: For a more detailed formulation of this inequality see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma

Comment: If we have a curve parametrized as $\gamma(t)$ (here $t$ is a real parameter that tells you how far along the curve you are) then $\int_\gamma f(z)dz = \int f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) dt$ (and for your second integral what is meant by $d|z|$ is simply $|\gamma'(t)|dt$). In your case $\gamma(t) = t + iT$ and the limits of integration goes from $t = c$ to $t = \infty$.

Comment: Ah yes when I spell it out using that definition it works, thanks.

Comment: Is it $d|z|$ or $|dz|?$ The latter makes more sense.

Comment: It was $d|z|$ but later $|dz|$ was also used. I agree that the latter makes more sense.